# Convert a normal mp4 into a 180 VR

Tags: ffmpeg, aframe

If i open a "normal" video into aframe, it is incredibly distorded.

`<a-videosphere rotation="0 180 0" src="normal.mp4">`

Is there a way to convert any video into something that can be played without being distorded ?

Of course replacing missing chunks with black.

Edit : Let's say that videos are 16:9, if this is important.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a-video src="...">`. https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/primitives/a-video.html

Otherwise, normal videos cannot just be displayed at 180/360.

Comment: https://aframe.io/docs/master/primitives/a-video.html#sidebar